# Would vuex state management be useful in implementing a multi page app with django?

Tags: python, django, vue.js, vuex

I have created a single page app before with Vue and Vuex for state management and am looking into multi page apps with the django backend framework. I am curious to know if there would be any pros to including vuex state management or would the backend take care of state management in this case?

Comment: the answer to this question would take a few chapters in a book probably and boils down to philosophy ... as such i suspect this question will get nixxed :/ maybe go ask on quora or a site that is more appropos to this type of question (which is not a bad question... its just not a SO question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuex still has use cases, even if you are navigating (and thus clearing the store) between pages.

- You can create and restore a store from localStorage, allowing you to keep a local state between pages. Depending on how much data you try to store in the store this may be bad for performance.
- When communicating between components, you usually do this with the prefered method of using props and events. However, when two components do not have a direct relation with each other, passing data through several components is usually a burden. You can either use a vuex store to manage shared data, or use a bus to make that easier.

That said, you probably only want to add a store when you feel the need to have one. Adding a store is usually trivial.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify/ get some more info on what you said about navigating to different pages. So vuex will not persist between different pages and will clear when you navigate to different pages..? But multiple components on the same page can utilize the same vuex instance?

Comment: Yes. In a MPA you send requests for pages to the server just like you would in a static html website, and thus you lose everything between page requests. Other than that it is still a Vue application, so anything that is rendered with vue works just like it would in a SPA.